# Developing mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What is mvc ? What are the benefits developing mcv website ? How can I develop mvc website, that is what I have to install,I have installed microsoft visual studio 2005 in my pc then what I have to install to develop mvc website ? I am begginer in developing website.

And which are the best free resource I can use to learn how to develop best mvc website,like ebooks or anything  ?

Please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below links will surely help you to understand MVC.

[ASP.NET MVC Framework Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx)

[ASP.NET MVC Framework Overview](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx)

[MVC 1 download details](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en)

Also now MVC 2 is avaliable.

Comment: I have install visual studio 2008 and if I try to install mvc 1.0 then there is error like first install 3.5 sp1. Then from where I can download it sp1 ?

Comment: ypu can get it from this link
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Two seminal examples have been published with lots of documentation:

**Nerd Dinner** : http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/
This was built against MVC 1.0 so some of the syntax is a bit outdated but is still applicable and it goes through several facets of your typical MVC application.  There is a link on the homepage there to a walk through available in PDF and HTML form.

**MVC Music Store** : http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/
This example is made to demonstrate some of the new MVC 2.0 features and other new MVC practices.  It also has a vast document walking through the creation of the website and its code.  Download the code and read the documentation.

These are by no means the best but it comes straight from the source (Microsoft dev team) and are a good start for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great place to start: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: but I have installed 2005 in my pc now then can I develop mvc website in 2005 ?

Comment: @Harikrishna I believe VS2008 is the 1st version to support ASP.net MVC but you can install them side by side and there are free express editions of Visual Studio

Comment: @TJB, if I install vs2008 express then mvc will come with it or I have to download and install it separately.

Comment: @Harikrishna VS2008 requires a seperate install, I would recommend installing VS2010 which comes with MVC2.0 installed out of the box.  Express editions are available for both.

Comment: @TJB, but I have already downloaded free express 2008 then for mvc download what should I do ?

Comment: @Harikrishna Again, I would recommend just starting with VS2010 express, but I believe the 2008 install can be found here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en look for 2008

Comment: @TJB, no I have already downloaded 2008 but now I want to download mvc for that.

Answer (score 0):

The reference @Kane gave it great. There are a number of tutorials and videos. But you can also read some blogs like: haacked.com or http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/.

Also there is a great codeplex project kigg that is good to look over and review.

http://kigg.codeplex.com/

Those are a few more resources to consider. Also don't forget here on SO. There are a lot of the problems that people have encountered and can be a good resource.